# Django migration gives psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation error

Tags: django, postgresql, dbmigrate, makemigrations

I have previously restored the database for the system, and while i tried to migrate through the django applicaion, the following error is thrown. What is the possible cause and how can we mitigate such cases. I guess the problem is with the existing table conflict, will it solve the issue by delete/dropping the conflicting tables.

````
  Applying introduction.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HG\Desktop\RC\SB\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "introduction_introduction" already exists


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:  

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\HG\Desktop\RC\SB\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\HG\Desktop\RC\SB\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\HG\Desktop\RC\SB\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\HG\Desktop\RC\SB\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\HG\Desktop\RC\SB\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HG\Desktop\RC\SB\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 231, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Users\HG\Desktop\RC\SB\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\HG\Desktop\RC\SB\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\HG\Desktop\RC\SB\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\HG\Desktop\RC\SB\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\HG\Desktop\RC\SB\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", line 92, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "C:\Users\HG\Desktop\RC\SB\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 324, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "C:\Users\HG\Desktop\RC\SB\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 142, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\HG\Desktop\RC\SB\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute  
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\HG\Desktop\RC\SB\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute   
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\HG\Desktop\RC\SB\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\HG\Desktop\RC\SB\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute  
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\HG\Desktop\RC\SB\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\HG\Desktop\RC\SB\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute  
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "introduction_introduction" already exists```
````

Comment: If I get stuck like this, I will often temporarily comment out the commands that are throwing the error. That would be if I know that the stat of my database is okay. Obviously that's not going to cut it in prod, but I find with development it's usually just good enough to get the migrations to run. Also you could manually drop the offending table if that's better for you.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and solved it by deleting the database a running the inital migrations again